# Saving multiple image input using Intervention\Image

Tags: php, forms, image, laravel

Trying to make an photo uploader using [Intervention\Image](http://image.intervention.io/api/) 
I have this in ReportController@store :

```
public function SavePhoto($photo){
        $file_ext = $photo->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $file_name = uniqid();
        $photo_name = $file_name. '.' . $file_ext;
        $path = public_path('uploads/photos/' . $photo_name);
        Image::make($photo)->resize(300, null, function ($constraint) {
            $constraint->aspectRatio();
        })->save($path);
        return $photo_name;
    }

public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $observation = new Observation();
        $observation->content = $request['Observation'];
        $observation->status_id = $request['Status'];
        $photo = Input::file('photo');

        foreach ($photo as $p){
            $this->SavePhoto($p);

        }
```

I am so confused of how to call the SavePhoto() method for all photos input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Laravel API docs use the [allFiles()](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_allFiles) method to get the files of `$request`.

```
$photos = $request->allFiles();
foreach ($photos as $photo){
    $this->SavePhoto($photo);
}
```

I haven't tried it though. :)
its the equivalent of getting the $_FILES array

```
foreach($_FILES as $photo) {
    $this->SavePhoto($photo);
}
```

Comment: I tried it but but $photos is returning an empty array :-  $photo = Input::allFiles();
return $photo; ==> {"photo":{}}

Comment: I corrected the mistake in my code. $_FILES is the name of the superglobal.  Is the $_FILES array empty? If not, you check if you submitted it correctly and the data arrives.

Comment: I changed my code, the allFiles() method is part of Request object.

Comment: Still having a empty return ->  $photo = $request->allFiles();
return $photo;
result=> {"photo":{}}
This is my input code : <input name="photo" type="file"  multiple>

Comment: could you show the dump of `$_FILES` in your target script?